# Retrieving extra variables from php function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to return three arguments from the expense table I have in my database.
This is my function which is located in users.php

```
public function expense($username, $i) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `expenses` WHERE `username`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $i=1;
    $totalSpent=0;

    try{

        $query->execute();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
                    print "Username: " .  $row['username'] .", Amount: ". $row['amount'] ."$, Type: ". $row['type'] .", Date: ". $row['date'] .", Comment: ". $row['comment']   . ".<br>";
                    $totalSpent+=$row['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }

        return $query->fetch();
        return $i;
        return $totalSpent;

    } catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

I have set it up in my view.php file to retrieve the columns matching the username like this:

```
        <?php
    $users->expense($username);
    ?>
```

My issue is I'm sending one argument (`$username`) to the function, but as per the function, I also want to retrieve `$i` (which is actually the count of rows) and the  `$totalSpent` which is the total count of amount rows.

Viewing the rows works fine, but I tried in multiple ways but couldn't manage to to retrieve back the `$i` and `$totalSpent` variables.

I am quite new, at this so I'm looking forward to suggestions on how to make my code better, if I've done things wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only return one item from a function call, so make that item an array or an object:

```
return array(
    'results' => $query->fetch(),
    'i' => $i,
    'totalSpent' => $totalSpent
);
```

access using:

```
$returnValues = $users->expense($username);
$userQueryResult = $returnValues['results'];
```

but as you're using a class, you could also set public class properties with those values, and then just access the object properties from outside the method

```
public function expense($username, $i) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `expenses` WHERE `username`= ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $username);
    $i=1;
    $totalSpent=0;

    try{

        $query->execute();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
                    print "Username: " .  $row['username'] .", Amount: ". $row['amount'] ."$, Type: ". $row['type'] .", Date: ". $row['date'] .", Comment: ". $row['comment']   . ".<br>";
                    $totalSpent+=$row['amount'];
                    $i++;
                }

        $this->queryResult = $query->fetch();
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->totalSpent = $totalSpent;

    } catch(PDOException $e){

        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

and access using

```
$users->expense($username);
$userQueryResult = $users->queryResult;
```

etc.

This latter would be a cleaner approach

Comment: Good suggestion. And how do I later on view it in my view.php file ?

Comment: You are right ! I just managed to make it work ! Thanks a lot Mark !